# libxml2 or lxml error when trying to run the Scrapy Dmoz demo code

Tags: python, scrapy

```
File "/root/my_new_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scrapy/selector/dummysel.py", line 16, in _raise
    raise RuntimeError("No selectors backend available. " \
exceptions.RuntimeError: No selectors backend available. Please install libxml2 or lxml
```

I have libxml2 and lxml installed.  Any ideas why I'd be getting this error?

Comment: Did you install lxml into `python2.6` dir? Maybe your have multiple version of python.

Comment: I do have multiple versions of Python.  How can I make sure that I install it into the python2.6 dir?  Install from source?

Comment: try this command: `python2.6 -c 'import lxml'`

Comment: Thanks Kev.  That doesn't work, so I guess I don't have lxml installed for the python I'm trying to use.

Comment: Long story made short: I'm using virtualenv to select the python env I want.  pip and easy_install failed to install lxml in virtualenv due to a gcc error.  I installed python26-devel, reinstalled scrapy, installed the dev versions of lxml and libxml and reinstalled  zope.interface.  Scrapy works.

Comment: I had this problem but I only have python2.7 installed. Solution for me wast to do 'sudo aptitude install python2.7-libxml2', i had previously installed the libxml2 package and the -dev variant without luck.